# Finer(larger) basis, then finer(larger) topology

Tags: general-topology

I want to check a simple question. Is the following statement correct?

> Suppose $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology with basis $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{T}'$ is a topology with basis $\mathcal{B}'$. If  $\mathcal{B} \subseteq\mathcal{B'}$, then  $\mathcal{T}\subseteq\mathcal{T}'$

I think it is correct, since topology is just a set of all possible unions of basis elements, and since $\mathcal{B} \subseteq\mathcal{B'}$, the union generated by them also must follow the same relation, i.e $\mathcal{T}\subseteq\mathcal{T}'$.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you (again!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes. A quick argument shows: Let $U \in \mathcal{T}$. Then $U = \bigcup_\alpha B_\alpha$ for $B_\alpha \in \mathcal{B}$. Since $\mathcal{B} \subseteq \mathcal{B'} \subseteq \mathcal{T}'$, we have $U = \bigcup_\alpha B_\alpha \in \mathcal{T}'$.

Comment: Just as I thought. Thanks for your answer!